# Searching two sites at once using Google?

Tags: search, google

How can I limit a Google search to **two** sites at once?

I can search Serverfault by doing `site:serverfault.com windows xp`, but I can't seem to figure out how to include another site in my search.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It [appears to work](http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=vbscript+site:serverfault.com+OR+site:stackoverflow.com&btnG=Search&meta=) by doing this:

```
vbscript site:serverfault.com OR site:stackoverflow.com
```

Of course, this could be a false positive and would require further testing

Edit:
It definitely works, as demonstrated in the Results Summary:

> Results 1 - 10 of about 9,080 **from serverfault.com OR stackoverflow.com for vbscript.** (0.06 seconds)

Comment: Further confirmation: http://www.google.com/search?q=termcap+site:serverfault.com+OR+site:stackoverflow.com - the first two results are one from each of the sites. By using a less common search term, you don't need to page through so many entries to find the confirmation (or rely only on the summary).

Comment: @Dennis - in my example, the 5th result is from serverfault.com...